# What is a database n-way join?

Tags: join, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

What is a database n-way join?

Have searched a lot but cant find a definition or example.

Posting this on SO vs dba.stackexchange as it is more a database development question than a database administration question.

[image]

Source: The Data Warehouse Toolkit by Ralph Kimball, page 16.

Answer (score 3):

In mathematics and computer science, any time you see the number 'n', it is a placeholder for any integer, however a 2-way join is just a join.  An n-way join is a 3-way join, a 4-way join, a 12-way join, a 100-way join, etc.

Comment: I misread the wording prior to your edit, the wording is clearer now.

Answer (score -1):

(a,b) |><| (b,c) |><| (d,e) is a 3-way join

(a,b) |><| (b,c) |><| (d,e) |><| (e,f) |><| (f,g) is a 5-way join